# get only those mail which are send through email reply with attachment in node js

Tags: node.js, email, outlook, imap, email-attachments

Hi,i am trying to get only those emails which are received as email reply send by my system.for more specific i am sending email with attachment .and receiver replies to that email with attachment.

I want history of email in my system which shows which attachment is received against which email. for example if i have send email to pearson B.Pearson B will reply to that email.i want history of this.

I am able to send and receive email.But the issue is that i am getting all email fetched  betwwen a and b(I want only those email which is send as reply of particular email).Below i gave given code to fetch email.

```
async function mailreply(req, res) {
    Employee.email_reply(req.params.email, function (err, employee) {
         
         var imapConfig = {
            user: '*****',
            password: '****',
            host: 'imap-mail.outlook.com',
            port: 993,
            tls: true,
            tlsOptions: {
                rejectUnauthorized: false
            }
        };

        var imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
        imap.once("ready", checkMail);
        imap.once("error", function (err) {
            console.log("Connection error: " + err.stack);
        });
        imap.connect();
        function checkMail() {
            imap.openBox("INBOX", false, function (err, mailBox) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return;
                }
                imap.search(["UNSEEN", ["FROM", req.params.email]], function (err, results) {
                    if (!results || !results.length) {  
                        req.flash('error', 'No reply from selected user.')  
                        res.locals.message = req.flash();   
                        res.redirect(nodeSiteUrl+'/dashboard');  
                        imap.end(); return; }
                });
            });
        }
        
        
        
        
        var mailListener = new MailListener({
              username: "******",
              password: "******",
              host: "imap-mail.outlook.com",
              port: 993, // imap port
              tls: true,
              connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
              authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
              tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
              mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
              searchFilter: [ 'UNSEEN', ['FROM', req.params.email] ], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved , 
              markSeen: false, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
              fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
              mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
              attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
              attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments
        });
            
        mailListener.start();
        
        mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
          console.log("imapConnected");
        });
        
        mailListener.on("error", function(err){
          console.log('hello');
        });

        mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes){
            console.log(seqno)
            let attachments = [];
            var attachment = mail.attachments;
            if(attachment) {
                for(var i = 0, len = attachment.length; i < len; ++i){
                    attachments.push(attachment[i].fileName);
                }
            }
            passDatatoPage(mail, attachments);
            mailListener.stop();
        }) 
       
        mailListener.on("attachment", function(attachment){
            let filepath = './public/attachment/receive/';
            let output = fs.createWriteStream(filepath + attachment.fileName);
            attachment.stream.pipe(output).on("end", function () {
                console.log("All the data in the file has been read");
            }).on("close", function (err) {
                console.log("Stream has been cloesd.");
            });  
        });
    
    
        function passDatatoPage(mail, attachments) {
            var sender = mail.to[0].address;
            var senderName = mail.from[0].name;
            var reciver = mail.from[0].address;
            const date = moment(mail.date).format('LL');
            var subject = mail.subject;
            var message = mail.text;
            //console.log(attachments);
            var result = attachments.map(function(val) {
                return val;
            }).join(',');
            var attachmentArr = result.split(',');
            console.log(attachmentArr)
            res.render('email-reply', { title: 'Email Reply', to: sender, senderName: senderName, from: reciver, date: date, subject: subject, msg: message, attachments: attachmentArr});
        }
        
    });
};
exports.mailreply = mailreply;
```

In this code i am getting header error shown here
[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6DS9.png)

May I know what is wrong with my code?
please provide possible solution in this code or provide way how i achive my task.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not post code or errors as images.  Use copy and paste and provide it in text so future users can find it with search functions.  The windows console does support copy and paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do two things

1. when you send email store message id in database
2. get that message id and change search filter acording to below code
   (use below search filter to find message by id)

```
var mailListener = new MailListener({
              username: "HR2@almashriq.edu.sa",
              password: "Tab13510",
              host: "imap-mail.outlook.com",
              port: 993, // imap port
              tls: true,
              connTimeout: 10000, // Default by node-imap
              authTimeout: 5000, // Default by node-imap,
              tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
              mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
              searchFilter: [ ['HEADER','IN-REPLY-TO',messageId] ], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved , 
              markSeen: false, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
              fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
              mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
              attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
              attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments
        });
```

Comment: Is there a documentation for the possible values in `searchFilter` ?